# Is there a way to collect WMI or WBEM/CIM data with Collectd?

Tags: windows, monitoring, wmi, collectd

I've got an Ubuntu server running statsd, collectd and Graphite. I'm looking to collect data from Windows servers via WMI. I don't see an official plugin for WMI or WBEM/CIM on Collectd's web site. Is there a third party plugin available, or some kind of translation layer I might be able to put in place?

Answer (score 0):

[WMI Client for Linux](http://www.orvant.com/packages/)

You'll have to build it from source if you're not using a Debian derivative, but I use this with Nagios and a couple of other homebrew applications. It's a WMI client and is capable of running pretty much any WMI query and results can be dumped and rearranged using any of the standard *nix manipulation tools.

Comment: The link is dead.